# Names of the associated products of a configurable product are not visible in admin? Simple Configurable Products by Organic Internet

Tags: configurable-product

Simple problem - the simple associated product names are not showing in the associated products tab within configurable products in the Magento admin.

I'm running the [Simple Configurable Products extension by Organic Internet](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)

[image]

Someone posted a solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927616/2565123

But the fix is not working in my 1.9.1.0 project.

Could really do with some help on this - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late, but I had the same issue today.

The fix for me was in the file app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Grid.php, changing this line:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

with

```
parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Hope it helps somebody.